# How do I detect text alignment for a CEdit control?

Tags: mfc

How can I detect the existing text alignment for a CEdit control? I want to determine if the alignment is ES_LEFT or some other alignment.

I tried detecting the style in the WINDOWINFO, but this does not work.

```
WINDOWINFO wi;
wi.cbSize = sizeof(WINDOWINFO);
edit1->GetWindowInfo(&wi);
if (wi.dwExStyle & ES_LEFT || wi.dwStyle & ES_LEFT)
{
    CString Str; // breakpoint.
}
else
{
    CString Str; // breakpoint.
}
```

Comment: The edit1 variable points to a CEdit control that has left-alignment set.

Comment: Try `switch(edit1->GetStyle() & (ES_LEFT | ES_CENTER | ES_RIGHT)) { case ES_LEFT: ...}`. Those are window styles, not extended styles. Also, `ES_LEFT` is defined as `0`, so checking with `& ES_LEFT` alone can never work

Comment: Thanks. This works with the window style: if (edit1->GetStyle()  |  ES_LEFT) bitwise or instead of AND

Comment: No, that's equivalent to `if (edit1->GetStyle())` since `ES_LEFT` is `0`. It will evaluate to true if any of the style bits are set, which is *not* what you want to test. If you want to just check for left-alignment use `if((edit1->GetStyle() & (ES_LEFT | ES_CENTER | ES_RIGHT)) == ES_LEFT) {...}`. If you want to determine the alignment use the `switch` from my first comment.

Comment: Don't edit the answer into your question. If you want to share your answer, post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks dxiv.  This works for determining if left-alignment is being used or not.

```
if ((edit1->GetStyle() & (ES_LEFT | ES_CENTER | ES_RIGHT)) != ES_LEFT)
{
    // left-alignment not used. 
}
```